# useEffect is not called appropriate time, so useState in useEffect is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I wanna display realtime data array(JSON form) from the server.

```
function ServerTest(){
    var a  = new Array();
    const client = createClient();
    const queue = v4();

    var a  = new Array();
    var cl = new Array();
    const [valueA, setValueA]=useState(a)

    client.onConnect = function () {
        subscribe(client, 'admin', queue, (payload:any) => { 
            
            var c : any;
            var tmp: any
            a=payload.Conversations
            if(a!==null){
                a.map((item:any)=>{
                    cl.push(item.name)
                })
               
            }
            
        });
        
        publish(client, 'api', 'admin', queue, {});

    }
    client.activate();
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        setValueA(cl)
        console.log(valueA)
    },cl)
    
    return (         
    <div>A: {valueA} </div>
    )
}

export default ServerTest
```

In useEffect, console.log(valueA) is working but only setValueA(cl) is not working.
I think it is because useEffect is not called when 'cl' is changing.

Comment: I wanna get array of data and show them on view without button click or anything. But this code shows nothing. Thankyou and I edited my question

Comment: Are you expecting the onConnect and activate functions to run? I believe useEffect will run first when the component is mounted and only once given you passed `[]` as second arg.

Comment: If you're expecting data back from `client.activate()` you can add that inside useEffect. If the method is async, then add the right keywords. And if you want client.activate to run throughout the lifecycle of the component, then add it inside another useEffect.

Comment: You aren't using appropriate React principles. What library are you using to communicate with the server?

Comment: You should probably change your question to something like "How do I update my component state based on live updating data". You should also provide more context; you reference a number of functions that aren't defined in a way we can see, or reference a library. It's hard to provide meaningful advice with the information provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is React doesn't know that your `cl` variable has changed (because it's not a state)

Besides, you don't need `cl` in the first place.

Just wrap the initial connection in useEffect and call `setValueA` when you got the data.

```
function ServerTest(){    
    const queue = v4();
    const [valueA, setValueA]= useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        const client = createClient();
        client.onConnect = function () {
            subscribe(client, 'admin', queue, (payload:any) => { 
                if(payload.Conversations!==null){
                    setValueA(payload.Conversations.map((item:any)=>item.name))
                }
                
            });
            publish(client, 'api', 'admin', queue, {});
        }
        client.activate();
    }, [])
    
    return (         
    <div>A: {valueA} </div>
    )
}
```